# непонятное с синтаксисом оператора `array_rand`

Tags: php, случайные-числа

Синтаксис `array_rand`, гласит: `array_rand ( array input [, int num_req] )`, где `num_req` - количество выбираемых значений.

Тогда почему при установке параметра `num_reg` в значение 1, рандом перестаёт работать?
Т.е. пример №1:

```
$input = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13);
$rnd_key = array_rand($input, 1); // вот тут поставим "1" (в нём-от и загвоздка)
$rnd = $input[$rnd_key[0]]; // тут ни чего не получим(!)
```

пример №2

```
$input = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13);
$rnd_key = array_rand($input, 2); // тут ставим 2 и всё начинает работать.
$rnd = $input[$rnd_key[0]]; // тут получим нужное нам, выбранное рандомно, значение.
$rnd_2 = $input[$rnd_key[1]]; // тут ещё можем получить и второе значение, которое нам, допустим, и не нужно даже.
```

Вопрос: почему первый пример не работает?

Comment: Проверьте в первом примере - действительно ли полученный $rnd_key содержит МАССИВ, а не скалярное значение (если второй параметр опустить - возвращается именно скаляр).

Comment: @Akina Напишите это в ответ

Comment: @Akina, как раз это я и замечал, так как у меня массив из других числел, трёхзначных. Теперь понял, значит нужна правка вывода значения, на `$rnd = $input[$rnd_key];`! Спасибо. Теперь все в голове с пониманием механизма num_req, встало на свои места.

Comment: @tutankhamun Пжалста...

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте в первом примере - действительно ли полученный $rnd_key содержит МАССИВ, а не скалярное значение (если второй параметр опустить - возвращается именно скаляр).

Для того, чтобы всегда получать массив, воспользуйтесь советом **qeremy** из [usernotes к документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-rand.php#107813)

> And example for getting random value from assoc arrays
>
> ```
> <?php
> function array_random_assoc($arr, $num = 1) {
>     $keys = array_keys($arr);
>     shuffle($keys);
>
>     $r = array();
>     for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
>         $r[$keys[$i]] = $arr[$keys[$i]];
>     }
>     return $r;
> }
>
> $a = array("a" => "apple", "b" => "banana", "c" => "cherry");
> print_r(array_random_assoc($a));
> print_r(array_random_assoc($a, 2));
> ?>
> ```
>
> Output
>
> ```
> Array
> (
>     [c] => cherry
> )
> Array
> (
>     [a] => apple
>     [b] => banana
> )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы выбираете только одно значение, функция array_rand() возвращает **ключ**, соответствующий этому значению.

В обратном случае, она возвращает **массив ключей**, соответствующих случайным значениям.

Пример для одного числа https://eval.in/754748 и для двух https://eval.in/754750